# How can I add a hand-spritz to this shower setup?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

I have the shower shown below. Shower works great, and has lots of flow.

But... I need to add a hand spritz to it.

I see two paths:

- Change the shower arm to one with a diverter
- Switch to a shower column

The problem with the diverter approach is that the valve would be really high up. None of us would be able to reach it!

The problem with the shower column is that it would be a big rework, and require drilling through tile. Drilling is not possible.

How to approach so that can used by folks of normal height?

References to specific parts appreciated.

(Cannot get in the wall or change the valve...)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Detail of joint]

Put a wrench on the flats and unscrew that joint. Then find an adapter to fit those threads that includes the hand-shower function.

Probably will be difficult to find as it appears to be "deliberately large to impress" rather than standard shower fitting size.

There is a standard method to operate a valve out of reach overhead. A lever with pull chains is fitted and the pull chains are in reach.

[image: Speakman shower valve image from eyewashdirect.com]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the arm with an elbow

[image]

Get a *single* shower head on a bar that doubles as overhead or handheld, and connect it to the elbow.  Perhaps buy a longer hose if needed.

[image]

**Or** get a two-head (overhead and hand) shower bar with a diverter knob *at the bottom* that mounts to the wall *and connects to the elbow with a hose, not directly to the ear*.   Replace the included short connector hose with a longer one to reach the high elbow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are shower bar systems that can be retrofitted to any shower without any drilling or cutting.  They are like this [shower system](https://www.lowes.com/pd/PULSE-Retro-Fit-Chrome-Shower-Bar-System/1002937958?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-bth-_-ggl-_-PLA_BTH_225_Faucets-Showerheads-And-Bath-Decor-_-1002937958-_-online-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=Cj0KCQiApKagBhC1ARIsAFc7Mc5xJXyZsis4tjXWKzNIgvdnJXsaMJ3gd3YJybbfV-b-zgDP-Up_wG0aAi-WEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

I have installed many over a period of about 7 years and have one in my own home.

( I am not advocating for this particulay brand, but the type of system.)

On this type the divertor is at the bottom of the column and easy to reach for everybody.

You replace the shower arm with a nipple that is supplied and everything else is included.  You can even attach the bottom of the bar with a super sticky pad and don't need to drill.

Comment: The link you posted seems broken?

Comment: So, the system connection to the nipple is in the top bracket and the diverter knob is at the bottom?  If so this works well and the available options are far greater than the ones I suggested in my answer, where the connection is via a connecting hose.  There do not seem to be many of those.  But you would have to make sure it's configured this way.   Also, OP's nipple is unusually high, that needs to be considered.